# How to check if any part of an input is part of a list in python

Tags: python

So I want to make a bot that tells jokes but I am having trouble checking if any part of an input is part of a seperate list. So for instance (side note: this is all in a while loop):

```
punWords = [pun, Puns]
userInput = input('What kind of jokes do you want to hear?')

elif userInput in punWords:
     print(random.choice(punJokes))
     print(random.choice(jokeResponses))
     print(' ')
     jokeFunc2()
else:
     print('Sorry I dont know any of these jokes')
```

The problem im having is that if the user inputs something like "I want to hear a pun" Then it goes through and compares every word to punWords and if it doesn't match then it prints the `"Sorry I don't know any of these jokes"` message so that the output ends up looking something like this:

> 'Sorry I dont know any of these jokes'
>
> 'Sorry I dont know any of these jokes'
>
> 'Sorry I dont know any of these jokes'
>
> 'Sorry I dont know any of these jokes'
>
> 'Sorry I dont know any of these jokes'
>
> 'Insert pun joke'

What I want to happen is that it only prints the error message if the input doesnt match any of the other words. Thanks a lot for any help and sorry if the post isnt done right (this is my first time posting on any kind of forum).

Comment: Right now, we can't run this and see the incorrect behavior because your code is incomplete. Please add a complete, reproducible example. As-written, it looks like your code should only do this check once, so there is clearly something left out.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to count the number of matches.  Then if there are zero matches, print the error message.  Something like:

```
if userInput in punWords:
   matchedWords += 1
```

then after the while loop

```
if matchedWords:
   # do your thing
else:
   print ("Sorry I don't know any of these jokes")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for the intersection between two lists (the list of pun words and the list of words entered), which can be performed using a Python set:

```
words = userInput.split()
if (set(words) & set(punWords)):
    print(random.choice(punJokes))
```

or more simply demonstrated:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,4,5]
print(list(set(a) & set(b))) #result: [3]
```